# How to get google UserID by email or GoogleDrive permissionId

Tags: google-apps-activity

Google Drive returns:

- user email
- permission Id

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions

Google Drive Activity API v2 returns Google UserID, example: 
personName: people/ACCOUNT_ID
https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/reference/rest/v2/activity/user#KnownUser

How can I match user email OR userPermissionId against 'people/ACCOUNT_ID' ?

Is there a way I can get ACCOUNT_ID having user email/permissionId or vice versa?

Comment: By `people/ACCOUNT_ID` doy you mean the `resourceName` returned by the [People API](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/listDirectoryPeople?)?

Comment: Yep, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

### Provided you have the [personName](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/reference/rest/v2/activity/user#KnownUser) from the Drive Activity API:

- This name corresponds to the People API [resourceName](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person)
- Make a [people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) request specifying the `resourceName` of form `people/xxxxx` and set `personFields` to `emailAddresses` and `fields` to `emailAddresses/value`
- The Drive API v3 method [Permissions: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) will return you all existing permission ids and matching `emailAddresses` for a specified file
- There is no way to filter [Permissions: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) results directly by `emailAddresses`, so you would need to implement a programmatic functionality to compare all permissions for a file against a certain user name

Comment: as mentioned by @PlugHead, when you request `people.get`, you'll NOT get the email address if the person is not in your contact list.

Comment: FYI, if you add `emailAddresses/value` in the `fields`, I get an empty result. Removing `fields` works as expected.

Comment: I see two workarounds for now:

1. Use `people.get` and request `photos`, you can use this API without Oauth (i.e. request public info). Then match the `photo.url` from the response with the photo url returned by Drive API.

2. Match the [Drive.Changes.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/list) timestamp with Drive Activity timestamps. If `Activity.timestamp` is **almost** the same as the `Drive.Change.timestamp` then the `lastModifyingUser` is probably the `Person`. By 'almost' I mean a very short interval (up to a second).

Comment: I've created an issue that was accepted: (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130103879)

Answer (score 1):

[people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) request will give you nothing if resourceName not equal to people/me or person not in your contact list.